# Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid - download excel through php

Tags: php, excel

There are variants of this question. Unfortunately they couldn't help me.

The below code works perfectly fine (using slim). User header() if not using slim.

```
    $response = $res->withHeader('Content-Description', 'My File transfer')
     ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
     ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.basename($filePath).'"')
     ->withHeader('Expires', '0')
     ->withHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
     ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate')
     ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public')
     ->withHeader('Content-Length', filesize($filePath));

    readfile($filePath);
```

I tried ob_start, flush, end combination from the other answers but nothing helped.

I was able to open the file on the server but as soon as I tried to open it after download through above code Excel could not open it - Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Open the files (source and downloaded) in hex to look for any obvious difference.

In my case it was a leading 0d0a (line feed and carriage return)

This was coming from a new line after ?> (php close tag) !!! I removed the new line after ?> and I could get it working (could open the file)

I hope it helps someone. Just lost 3 hours figuring out.

Comment: but how did the line feed get in the file? This does not tell you how to fix the code just how to find the problem

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear with the answer. The code flow includes other dependent php files. One of the files had a new line after ?> (manual error). This new line was causing issue when sending a binary output. It works well with json as the new lines are ignored on the json parsers. I had to find the file which had new line after ?> and remove it to fix the problem. It was suggested in many answers to use ob_clean but that didn't fix the problem either. So my conclusion is, code fix couldn't help in this situation and it was the syntax.

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593326/unwanted-new-line-returned-after-ajax-request